# Why run guake by python2 but there are 'python3' in errors?

Tags: python, archlinux

My os is archlinux.I have installed guake for a month and it works well.But today it can't start,and the errors is:

```
[arch@arch ~]$ python2 /usr/bin/guake
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/guake", line 34, in <module>
    import dbus
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/dbus/__init__.py", line 82, in <module>
    import dbus.types as types
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/dbus/types.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _dbus_bindings import (
ImportError: /usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/_dbus_bindings.so: undefined symbol: PyBytes_Type
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: If you start Python 2, what is the contents of `sys.path`? I suspect it has been messed up somehow and is finding Python 3 libraries.

Comment: You are right.How to fix it?

Comment: Remove the Python3 things from the path or remove the thing that puts them into the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that the **`PYTHONPATH`** was set to

```
/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages in /etc/profile
```

Comment this will solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `python2` symlink is pointing to python3 instead.
Try checking it using `which python2`. If it shows `python3` and if your `python3` symlink also ponts to python3 then you'll probably need to reinstall python2.

Answer (score 0):

To add to other answers, define PYTHONPATH like this:

```
> PYTHONPATH="..." python2 /usr/bin/guake
```

In this case you're only changing path for this execution.

Also you can use `env` in command line to check current PYTHONPATH value.

```
> env | grep PYTHONPATH
```